# How to compare two strings of EditText then highlight the different in Android?

Tags: java, android, arrays, spannablestring

I have 2 EditText strings that have to be compared, I know how to compare and get results like "OK" if both of them match and "NOK" if they don't match.
But I don't know how to find the different characters or parts.
As an example:

> EditText editTextStdCode = 18X2101UG1

Compare to

> EditText editTextActCode = 18Y2101UG1

the result is "NOK" because `editTextActCode` is different from `editTextStdCode` in section 18**Y**2101UG1, and I want to highlight the character Y because it is a different character from `editTextActCode`.

Things I've tried are using SpannableString like the following:

```java
private void highlightChar(Integer startSpan, Integer endSpan) {
    SpannableString spannableStr = new SpannableString(editTextActCode.getText().toString());
    BackgroundColorSpan backgroundColorSpan = new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN);
    spannableStr.setSpan(backgroundColorSpan, startSpan, endSpan, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    editTextActCode.setText(spannableStr);

}


/**
 *
 * @param editText
 * @param fIndex
 * @param lIndex
 * @param textToHighlight
 */
public void setHighLightedText(EditText editText, Integer fIndex, Integer lIndex, String textToHighlight) {
    String tvt = editText.getText().toString().substring(fIndex,lIndex);
    int ofe = tvt.indexOf(textToHighlight);
    Spannable wordToSpan = new SpannableString(editText.getText());
    for (int ofs = 0; ofs < tvt.length() && ofe != -1; ofs = ofe + 1) {
        ofe = tvt.indexOf(textToHighlight, ofs);
        if (ofe == -1)
            break;
        else {
            wordToSpan.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(0xFFFFFF00), ofe, ofe + textToHighlight.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            editText.setText(wordToSpan, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
        }
    }
}
```

But the results are not accurate. Please Help.

Comment: Does the both editText contain same number of characters?

Comment: Sometimes it's different, because i got those strings from OCR (Optical Character Recognition) and the example like: first string **18X2101UG1** and second string may be **18Y2101UG** or even be **18Y2101U**

Answer (score 6):

You need to execute a for loop and then get individual string characters and compare them:

```
StringBuilder sbedtstdcode = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder sbedtactcode = new StringBuilder();
String editTextStdCode = editTextStdCode.getText().toString();
String editTextActCode = editTextActCode.getText().toString();

for (int i = (editTextStdCode.length - 1); i >= 0; i--)
{
    String stdstr = editTextStdCode.charAt(i);
    String actstr = editTextActCode.charAt(i);
    if(stdstr.equals(actstr))
    {
       sbedtstdcode.append(stdstr.charAt(i));
       sbedtactcode.append(actstr.charAt(i));
    }       
    else
    {
       Spannable spactstr = new SpannableString(actstr);        
       actstr.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 
       Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
       s.append(spactstr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the code has some errors, like ```String actstr = editTextActCode.charAt (i);``` must be char, whereas ```editTextActCode``` is String. Then in the line ```actstr.setSpan (new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE)...```, it says "Cannot resolve **setSpan**..." and another in the code ```s.append(spactstr);``` "Cannot resolve symbol **s**"